# CSS in Visual Flows

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow

I'm trying to control the look of a flow activated by a visual force page.
I tried the following and it doesn't work. Anyone knows how to do it?

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" standardStylesheets="false" >
    <style type="text/css">

    .theflow {

      background-color: #FF0000;

    }

</style>

    <div id="theflow">
    <flow:interview name="Basic_Trouble_Shooting" buttonLocation="top" buttonStyle="color:#800080; background-color:#fed; border:1px solid;">


    <apex:param value="{!Case.Id}" name="BTS_CaseID"/>    
    </flow:interview></div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: give # instead of #theflow {

      background-color: #FF0000;

    }

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: @Yameen what do you mean?

Comment: theflow is an id, so you have to refer it using a # symbol insted of . in your css

Comment: @Yameen Thx. it works but not on the flow. it's like the flow is a closed entity that i can't change.

Comment: @Yameen and here is a list of classes that i can supposedly change. that's why i tried also: .FlowText .FlowTextArea {

      background-color: #FF0000;

    }

Comment: @Yameen Ok .FlowRadio works but how can I change just free text I put in a display text box?